# QEMU VDE Network Backend Error

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

When I try to use the VDE network backend with a QEMU VM, an error is returned:

```
Parameter 'type' expects a netdev backend type
```

In an identical environment, but with QEMU built from source according to their documentation, this error does not happen, and the VM works as expected.

I am using a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS for testing using Vagrant to make sure that there is no variability when testing across atomic configuration and build changes. Here is the output from lsb_release -a

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy
```

Here are all the commands in Vagrant's install script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
## Set environment
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

## Update Ubuntu
sleep 20
echo 'APT::Get::Always-Include-Phased-Updates "1";' | tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/80PhasedUpdates
apt-get update
apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade -y
apt-get autoremove -y
apt-get autoclean -y
```

Here is the section of the script that installs QEMU and VDE2:

```bash
apt-get install -y qemu-system-x86 vde2
```

Here are the commands that I am using to start the VDE switch and the QEMU VM (I am running these two in separate tmux sessions because neither command is backgrounded:

```bash
vde_switch -sock /tmp/myswitch
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 8G -cpu host -enable-kvm -nic vde,sock=/tmp/myswitch
```

Here is the resulting error:

```
qemu-system-x86_64: -nic vde,sock=/tmp/myswitch: Parameter 'type' expects a netdev backend type
```

Comment: Hi @utkonos this won't work for now, VDE as a feature was always disabled (checked 18.04/20.04/22.04) for using dependencies that were not fully supported. We have over the recent years established a pattern that allows us to provide such features as opt-in. I've filed a bug (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qemu/+bug/1988704) to have a look at that in the coming Ubuntu release (as the current one is feature frozen already). Thanks for the report, consider subscribing to the LP bug.

Comment: Thanks so much. So, for today, I should examine how to create my own package / deploy a PPA that covers this, I think.

Comment: You can steal everything you need recipies, code, repositories, howto, ... from https://launchpad.net/~canonical-server/+archive/ubuntu/server-backports and do your version of it. Has the benefit that it auto-rebuilds whenever there is a fix to the underlying qemu that is in Ubuntu.